# Collinear vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I have 3 points and I want to prove that they are on the straight line the points are 
$$
A(0,0,2),\quad
B(0,0,-3),\quad
C(0,0,4)
$$
To prove that they are on the straight line we need to prove that 
$$
\vec AB \parallel \vec BC
$$
where
$$
\vec AB=(0,0,-5)
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\vec BC=(0,0,7).
$$
So $\displaystyle \frac {0}{0}≠ \frac {-5}{7}$

But if we try to graph those  points
It seems to be they are on the straight line
So please can Any one tell me what's the right.

Are they on straight line or not?!

Comment: Is not $(0,0,7)=-7/5(0,0,5)?$ That is, are not the vectors proportional? What do you mean by $0/0?$

Comment: @user11618 please note that all three of your points lie on the $z$-axis, so they are all colinear.

Comment: I took the $ \frac {x \vec AB }{x \vec BC} $

Comment: So they collinear vectors?

Comment: Thanks saqqib mahumoud and mfl for your time